# Not able to startActivity(intent) from onServiceConnected() of AccessibilityService

Tags: android, accessibilityservice

I am starting an activity from `onServiceConnected()` method of `AccessibilityService`.

I started `AccessibilityService` successfully but not able to start device admin intent from it.

I debug my app, service started successfully and `onServiceConnected()` is also called a `callDeviceAdmin()` is also executed without a crash, but still DeviceAdmin intent not starting.

```
public class AccessibilityEventService extends AccessibilityService {

    public static final int REQUEST_CODE_FOR_ACTIVE_DEVICE_ADMIN = 100;

    @Override
    public void onAccessibilityEvent(AccessibilityEvent event) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onInterrupt() {
        Log.d("TAG", "EXECUTE ON Interrupt");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onServiceConnected() {
        callDeviceAdmin();
    }


    private void callDeviceAdmin(){
        ComponentName mComponentName;
        DevicePolicyManager mDevicePolicyManager;
        mDevicePolicyManager = (DevicePolicyManager) getSystemService(Context.DEVICE_POLICY_SERVICE);
        mComponentName = new ComponentName(this, AdminReceiver.class);

        try{
            boolean isAdmin = mDevicePolicyManager.isAdminActive(mComponentName);
            if (!isAdmin) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(DevicePolicyManager.ACTION_ADD_DEVICE_ADMIN);
                intent.putExtra(DevicePolicyManager.EXTRA_DEVICE_ADMIN, mComponentName);
                intent.putExtra(DevicePolicyManager.EXTRA_ADD_EXPLANATION, "SaferCell wants device Administrator access");
                getApplicationContext().startActivity(intent);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d("onAccessibilityEvent", e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

**UPDATE**

```
public class AdminReceiver extends DeviceAdminReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onEnabled(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Toast.makeText(context, context.getString(R.string.device_admin_enabled), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence onDisableRequested(Context context, Intent intent) {
        return context.getString(R.string.device_admin_warning);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDisabled(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Toast.makeText(context, context.getString(R.string.device_admin_disabled), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onLockTaskModeEntering(Context context, Intent intent, String pkg) {
        Toast.makeText(context, context.getString(R.string.kiosk_mode_enabled), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onLockTaskModeExiting(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Toast.makeText(context, context.getString(R.string.kiosk_mode_disabled), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try your code as well, but I created a demo accessibility service to try this and worked fine.

You have to add Intent flag because you're starting an activity from outside of an Activity context requires the `FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK` flag.

```
 public class AccessibilityServiceDemo extends AccessibilityService {
        @Override
        public void onAccessibilityEvent(AccessibilityEvent accessibilityEvent) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onInterrupt() {

        }

        @Override
        protected void onServiceConnected() {
            super.onServiceConnected();
            System.out.println("onServiceConnected");
            Intent intent = new Intent().setComponent(new ComponentName("com.android.settings", "com.android.settings.DeviceAdminSettings"));
            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            startActivity(intent);

        }
    }
```

Comment: This is not the case. I want to active device admin from my app using `DevicePolicyManager.ACTION_ADD_DEVICE_ADMIN`

Comment: try with FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK

Comment: We can not use FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK with admin intent

Comment: Already Tried. Exception arrised that you can not use FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK with admin intent

Comment: Updated. Please check